# Unity Animation Event Function Call

Tags: function, events, animation, unity-game-engine, call

I have a main script running, using GUI and starting animation (which is part of another game object).

In this animation I want to have events which should call some function in the same script.

But when I am trying to do that.. there is just no function to choose from. It can be done only when the script is attached to a game object with that animation.
The problem is that I need some variables from the main script.

What solution would you recommend me?
Should I call another script which can somehow get variables from the main script or there is other way how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want can be achieved using static variables, but I personally prefer to use singletons on this kind of problem:
http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Singleton